# Connect 2 android device via httpClient httpServer

Tags: android

My problem is I need to connect two different android device via httpClient/httpServer. Since I do not know about is android devices support http connection I need help on this.

Comment: The devices support it, but mobile networks tend not to support incoming connections, so you will need to either put the devices on mutually routable wifi, or utilize a server on the publicly visible network to facilitate or at least help initiate the connection.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I have figured that out. For now wifi is or local networks are ok. Thank you